# Depth First Search adaptation for Graph Path

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph, depth-first-search

My problem is that I have been tasked with designing an efficient algorithm that given any undirected weighted graph G = (V,E,L) two nodes s, t ∈ V , and a maximum edge length L as inputs answers whether one can reach node t from node s or not.
The tough part is that my algorithm should run in time O(n + m)!

I already have a fair idea, I believe I need to use a Depth First Search, that is adapted using O(1) operations in order to preserve the running time. My feeling is that I need to add in conditional tests to a standard depth first search that finds a path between two nodes to compare if L <= currentEdgeLength, and only add the new node to the path if this condition is true.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The idea sounds right.

Comment: As for _adapted using O(1) operations_, I don't comprehend that, but when you store the graph as adjacency list, a straightforward depth-first search implementation indeed takes O (m + n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of both DFS and BFS is O(n + m) and so you can afford to run a new search for each query. What you propose is precisely the way I would approach this problem.